# Does Tableau have an analogue for dplyr::summarise_each and dplyr::mutate_each?

Tags: r, dplyr, tableau-api

Suppose I have a `data.frame` in R like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(population_id = 1:3,
                  person_years = c(500, 800, 300),
                  birth = c(20, 30, 40),
                  death = c(10, 50, 8))
```

Using `dplyr`, I could create birth and death rates easily with `mutate_each`.

```
dat <-
  dplyr::mutate_each(dat,
                     funs(get_rate = ./person_years,
                          count = as.numeric(.)),
                     births, deaths)
```

I could also use `dplyr::summarise_each` to get what I want if, say, each row were a `populated_id`-person-day pair with the number of births and deaths on that day (taking care to annualize the rates).

I want to do something similar in Tableau to avoid having to create calculated fields for the rates of each of several event types. It needs to be a calculated field because I want the annualized rate to be flexibly expressed at different levels of aggregation.

Comment: a humble suggestion - the way you phrased your question, only the people who know *both* R (dplyr, actually) and Tableau would be able to answer it - probably a very small number of people if you ask me...

Comment: Good point. If I get the time I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Tableau 9.1, you should be able to get pretty close to what you want with Tableau's Level of Detail calculations (see http://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/media/whitepaper_lod_eng_0.pdf).

An example LOD for the birth rates count would be `{FIXED [Population_Id] : SUM([Birth]) / SUM([Person_Years])}`. With that calculation, including an additional dimension such as `person_id` allows the calculation to work as expected.

That being said, I'd still process the data in `R` myself. :)

Comment: This solution still leaves the rest of the rates to be calculated in separate calculated fields using redundant code. I also would pre process the data myself but would rather have a solution that required only one data source per level of aggregation.

Comment: Agreed. You're hitting the limits of what you can do in Tableau though. If you're looking for maximum reproducability and DRY-ness, then you really should be looking at generating your visualizations from within R. Alternatively, you could explore some of the commercial interfaces with Tableau, such as Interworks Power Tools for Tableau (https://powertoolsfortableau.com/).